# Simulating objects with meta-tabl: table.insert returns "table expected, got nil"

Tags: object, lua, blackjack

So, here's the situation.

I'm making a blackjack game in the command line, so I build a Player "object" to be able to re-use functions for the user and the dealer(CPU). The whole game mechanic was working, except the ability to split hands. So, now I am going through my whole game to add the ability for the player to have multiple hands.

The meta-table is constructed like this:

```
function Player:new (o)
    o = o or {}   -- create object if user does not provide one
    setmetatable(o, self)
    self.__index = self
    self.total = 0 -- total of the hand (adding card values)
    self.money = 0 -- Remaining credits
    self.curHand = 1 -- Keeps track of the current hand being played and which bet to use
    self.split = 0 -- Keeps track of the total amount of times the hand was split (total number of hands)
    self.bet = {0, 0, 0, 0} -- 4 bets for the 4 possible hands after a Split
    self.insurance = 0 -- Amount being payed for insurance when dealer shows an Ace
    self.blackjack = false
    return o
end
```

The user and dealers are then instantiated like that:

```
user = Player:new({hand = {{}, {}, {}, {}}}) -- Instantiates the user and dealer objects
dealer = Player:new({hand = {}})
```

And my "hit" function is where my problems start.

```
function Player:hit(deck)
    table.insert(self.hand[self.curHand], draw(deck))
end
```

If I "rubber duck" the issue, my code should do the following:

```
1. user.hand starts as a table containing user.hand[1] through [4]
2. user.curHand == 1
3. So, user.hand[user.curHand] == user.hand[1] (for now at least)
4. table.insert will then add the first card (returned from the function "draw") to user.hand[user.curHand] ... in other words the first table of the four.
```

In the crash text, it tells that table.insert expected a table, but got nil, meaning there are no table at user.hand[1]... Keep in mind everything was working before I started adding the multiple hands.

I'm sure the solution is plain and simple, but I can't for the love of me figure it out. From my point of view, everything makes sense for it to work! (But, computers do *exactly* what we tell them to do... so I know I'm the issue )

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The code seems to work fine for me. I can't reproduce the error. There may be a problem outside the code that you've given us here. Please read [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You are so right!!

But! just that comment made me think about checking another detail... the DEALER's hand! THAT is where the issue was. Since the dealer was declared with only one table in "hand", it couldn't access dealer.hand[1].

So, the code I wrote here should work for the player, but not for the *dealer*, which I fixed by adding one more pair of curly braces: making it a table within the table.